# Wordpress custom form, loads wrong template after submit, doesn't send mail

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

Im trying to build a simple contact form for a Wordpress site. I want it to  send an email and reload the contact page it was sent from with an error/success message.

I have installed WP mail SMTP and it sends the test email.

Now to the problems. I have a form in html that I want to use. This form has been put in a custom template.

The php is borrowed from guides I have found online and I have used several of them. None of them work for me. When I hit the submit button the page loads the *base template* (not the custom template that I'm using for the form page) and no mail is sent. I want it to load the same page but with an error/success div telling me what happened. If I run the php before pressing submit it gives me the error message.

Here is my php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){
    //response generation function
    $response = "";

    //function to generate response
    function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $reason){

      global $response;

      if($type == "success") $response = "<div class='success'>{$reason}</div>";
      else $response = "<div class='error'>{$reason}</div>";

    }

    //response messages
    $not_human       = "Human verification incorrect.";
    $missing_content = "Please supply all information.";
    $email_invalid   = "Email Address Invalid.";
    $message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
    $message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";

    //user posted variables
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $human = 2;

    //php mailer variables
    $to = get_option('admin_email');
    $subject = "Someone sent a message from ".get_bloginfo('name');
    $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
      'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";



        if(!$human == 0){
        if($human != 2) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
        else {

            //validate email
            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
            else //email is valid
            {
            //validate presence of name and message
            if(empty($name) || empty($message)){
                my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
            }
            else //ready to go!
            {
                $sent = mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), 
$headers);
            if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", 
$message_sent); //message sent!
            else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", 
$message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
            }
            }
        }
        }

    else if ($_POST['submitted']) 
my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
    }
?>
```

Here is my html for the "print error/success" and the form:

```
<?php echo $response; ?>
<form class="interest-form" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Anmäl Intresse:</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Namn" name="name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['name']); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefonnummer" name="phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['phone']); ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-post" name="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['email']); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<?php the_field('fb_8_1_plats'); ?> <?php the_field('fb_8_1_startdatum'); ?>" readonly name="plats_datum">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="meddelande1">Meddelande:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="message" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message']); ?>" id="meddelande1"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
        <button type="submit" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Skicka intresseanmälan</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I really can't figure out what is wrong, I spent two full days just googling, trying and failing last weekend. After that I gave up and haven't looked at at for a week. Please help!

Edit: It doesn't load index.php, the path is still the same but it uses the template for index.php

Comment: I've had this happen before when posting a form variable that had the same name as a custom post type.  The form was posting to itself on an archive page that loaded all the custom post types.  When the form variable that had the same name of the post type got submitted it would load the wrong template.